# Security means before compiling the application

Tags: mysql, security, compilation

I have been writing database applications for a few years now but I have always ignored or - to use a better word - avoided the issue of securing the data in my source code.

I would eventually go with something like this (it's not an extract from my code; it's just to show you how obvious data are in the code):

```
procedure Something;
begin
  MySQLConnection.Host := '89.122.192.30';
  MySQLConnection.User := 'lumberjack';
  MySQLConnection.Password := 'aintgonnaguessitbabe2000';
end;
```

However, I have come across some warnings that doing something like this isn't safe because the connection data can be somehow retrieved by people who would eventually get my .exe file.

Now the question is - is that anyhow true? Are there any necessary security steps that I need to take when setting connection details? Is it necessary to somehow code the data so that it cannot be retrieved/guessed later on when .exe is published?

Comment: Yes; running `strings yourprog.exe` will show the strings.  It isn't hard to make guesses about which strings are used for which purposes.  You can consider masking or encrypting the strings, but even that isn't reliable.  As sufficiently dedicated hacker might spot the unusually random data and deduce that's the password encrypted — they're an incredibly persistent crew when the resource being protected is worth enough.  You should be looking alternative methods.

Comment: Do you know, perhaps, any sources that elaborate on the subject and should help in choosing the most efficient method to protect such vulnerable data? I'd be very grateful.

Comment: @Sates, which programming language are you using?

Comment: I'm building apps using Delphi in RAD Berlin 10.1 with licensed MyDAC.